# How can add parameter in htaccess for rewrite condition in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a below HTACCESS file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+viewgallery\.php\?cname=([^&\s]+)&pcaption=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^.]+)/$ /viewgallery.php?cname=$1&pcaption=$2 [L,NE]
```

Now i want to add 3rd parameter for search criteria q. How can i add this and how would i get that ?

Comment: Do you want to support URLs with 2 and 3 parameters both? Can you provide examples?

Comment: I want support for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+viewgallery\.php\?cname=([^&\s]+)&pcaption=([^&\s]+)&q=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/$ /viewgallery.php?cname=$1&pcaption=$2&q=$3 [L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a new set of rules for 3 parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+viewgallery\.php\?cname=([^&\s]+)&pcaption=([^&\s]+)&q=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} s/+viewgallery\.php\?cname=([^&\s]+)&pcaption=([^&\s]+)\s    
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/?$ /viewgallery.php?cname=$1&pcaption=$2&q=$3 [L,QSA,NC] 

RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^.]+)/?$ /viewgallery.php?cname=$1&pcaption=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```